# ffmpeg: filter frame using cuda

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda, nvenc

Is it possible to filter frames on nvidia GPU side?
For intel qsv it looks like

```
[sprites_src]vpp_qsv=framerate=1/10,scale_qsv=-1:160:mode=$mode:format=rgb32,hwdownload,format=rgb32[sprites_out];
```

For nvidia I have to use software filter

```
[sprites_src]scale_npp=-2:160:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload,format=nv12,framerate=fps=1/10[sprites_out];
```

But it is not optimal, because too many unnecessary frames will be uploaded to RAM.

I tried to looking for analogue `vpp_qsv` for nvidia, but did not find.